# How to cluster KML features in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, kml, clustering

Is it possible to cluster KML features in OpenLayers, and are there any samples?

I can find separate samples for clusters and KML but nothing which handles both together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible.  Add your KML file as layer type = Vector, protocol = HTTP, format = KML, and add a Fixed and a Cluster strategy to your list of strategies[].  Assuming you have code to work from since you mentioned you've seen examples of both.  If not, look at samples here:

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/

Comment: Vadim is correct, it works perfectly well.  UPVOTED! see this question for further explanations http://stackoverflow.com/q/15300467/1166727